# pagecontext request dispatcher servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, request, dispatcher, pagecontext

I am trying to forward a request using "RequestDispatcher". I have JSP pageContext object.
I tried to forward my request to my servlet "MyServlet" using the following code. I set some attributes in my request and forwarded it. But i am not able to access those variables in my servlet class.

My code :

```
pageContext.getRequest().setAttribute("AValue","A");
pageContext.getRequest().setAttribute("BValue", "B");

ServletContext context= pageContext.getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/MyServlet");
rd.forward(pageContext.getRequest(),pageContext.getResponse());
```

Help me !! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you showw the code what is the code in MyServlet to get attribute from request. The code written above along with question is this inside a jsp? If it is in jsp why don't you simply right request.setAttribute("AValue","A") instead of pageContext.getRequest().setAttribute("AValue","A"); because request is an implicit object in jsp.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I am using this code in one of my server codes. From my custom tag library class I got this pageContext object and passed it to my server class.In my server class based on some condition I forward the request to various servlets. Code to get the attribute values :

    String aValue = (String) request.getAttribute("AValue");

Answer (score 0):

When dynamically including or forwarding to a servlet from a JSP page, you can use a `jsp:param` tag to pass data to the servlet.

A `jsp:param` tag is used within a `jsp:include` or `jsp:forward` tag.

```
<jsp:include page="/servlet/MyServlet" flush="true" >
  <jsp:param name="AValue" value="A" />
  <jsp:param name="BValue" value="B" />
</jsp:include>
```

[Here is source docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/basics4.htm)

The use of scriptlets `<%  %>` in JSP is indeed highly discouraged since decade.
See [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am not forwarding my request directly from my JSP. I need to forward my request through RequestDispatcher. Is there any other way?

Comment: I tried the following code,

    pageContext.getRequest().setAttribute("check","checkValue");
    RequestDispatcher rd =      pageContext.getRequest().getRequestDispatcher("/MyServlet");
    rd.forward(pageContext.getRequest(),pageContext.getResponse());

and in my servlet class,
String v = (String) request.getAttribute("check");
       System.out.println("Check value  : " +v);

Still it is printing null value...Any idea?